# no audio after restarting laptop

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine: ASUSTeK X555LAB Laptop

Restarted my laptop today and can't get audio to work any help would be much appreciated

Comment: OK run all updates.  Then install Pulse audio Volume control.  Then restart. Play with pulse audio volume Control while a video is playing and see if you have any playback audio streams. Then see if you have sound on headphones.  Report back and we can go forward.

Comment: still no audio?

Comment: Check if any pulseaudio instance is running: pulseaudio --check. It normally prints no output, just exit code. 0 means running. ...
If any instance is running: pulseaudio -k to stop it.
Finally, start pulseaudio again as a daemon: pulseaudio -D.

Comment: just tried that and still out?

Comment: When you run pulse audio with a music file playing (with VLC or something) there is no playback streams at all?  Do you have an HDMI monitor hooked up?  They are notorious for grabbing system audio.

Comment: tested with vlc, audacity, and some sites on google cant get audio out of any of them I don't have any HDMI monitors I do have a VGA monitor but there's no sound with thought the VGA (no sound via built-in speakers and no sound output via headset either)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110111/discussion-between-usb-bunny-and-walttheboss).

Answer (score 1):

found a temp fix running `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` on every startup but will continue looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try these command to reset pulseaudio configuration:
`mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulseold`
`mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulseold`

One command may fails depending  config files location.
Reboot or restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`   to test